# C# WindowsForm GridView - How to add class into GridView?

Tags: c#, list, class, datagridview

```
public class PurchaseOrderItem
{
    public Int64 PONumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string UM { get; set; }
    public int QTY { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}

foreach (PurchaseOrderItem item in po.PurchaseOrderItems)
{
    dgvPOItem.Rows.Add(item);
}
```

The Foreach above isn't working.
I can't use DataSource since i need to add a blank row after adding the data 
So there will be a empty row where users can add values on gridview in the future.

Comment: Do you use Item/EditItem/Footer templates? The blank row could be created as part of the footer template, then you could simply bind your list of `PurchaseOrderItem`s to the grid as it is. Also, what's stopping you from appending an empty `PurchaseOrderItem` to your collection and then binding to `.DataSource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't you use a `BindingList<PurchaseOrderItem>` ?
this should allow you to add items to your collection from dgv control (using empty row)

---

Edit: I've created simple WinForm app,
only DGV control in the main form

Form1.cs code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

            list.Add( new PurchaseOrderItem() {
                PONumber = 1,
                Description = "First item",
                UM = "something",
                QTY = 2341,
                Cost = 0.99M
            } );

            dataGridView1.DataSource = list;

            dataGridView1.RowsAdded += new DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler( dataGridView1_RowsAdded );
        }

        void dataGridView1_RowsAdded( object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e ) {
            object o = list;    // added for breakpoint with variable viewing
            // you can watch your list changing here, when you add new rows
        }

        BindingList<PurchaseOrderItem> list = new BindingList<PurchaseOrderItem>();
    }

    public class PurchaseOrderItem {
        public Int64 PONumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string UM { get; set; }
        public int QTY { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    }
}
```